# How to Optimize 1024x1024 Matrix Multiplication in C to Match NumPy's Performance in M1 silicon

Tags: c, numpy, optimization, neon

I am working on optimizing a 1024x1024 matrix multiplication in C to match the performance of NumPy, which executes at approximately 90 GFlop/s using a single thread. My current C implementation reaches about 55 GFlop/s. I'm using ARM NEON intrinsics for vectorization and various block sizes for better cache utilization.

Here's my C code:

```c
#define N 1024
#define BLOCK_X 16 
#define BLOCK_K 8 
#define BLOCK_Y 8 
void matmul(float* const A, float* const B, float* const C){
    for(int by = 0; by < N; by+=BLOCK_Y) {
        for(int bx = 0; bx < N; bx+=BLOCK_X) {
            for(int bk = 0; bk < N; bk+=BLOCK_K) {
                for (int y=by; y<by+BLOCK_Y; y++){
                    for (int x=bx; x<bx+BLOCK_X; x+=4){
                        float32x4_t sum_vec = vld1q_f32(&C[y * N + x]);
                        __builtin_prefetch(&C[y * N + x + 4], 1, 0);
                        for (int k=bk; k<bk+BLOCK_K; k++){
                            float32x4_t a_vec = vdupq_n_f32(A[y * N + k]);
                            float32x4_t b_vec = vld1q_f32(&B[k*N+x]);
                            sum_vec = vmlaq_f32(sum_vec, a_vec, b_vec);
                        }
                        vst1q_f32(&C[y * N + x], sum_vec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the performance to be closer to NumPy's, but it's not there yet. What could be the bottlenecks or issues in my current implementation that are hindering its performance?

Comment: loop unrolling parallelisation? have you compiled with optimisations on? which ones?

Comment: I'm compiling with clang gemm.c -o gemm.out -O3 -march=native -ffast-math

Comment: The `x` loop should be unrolled too (so not just the inner most loop but the one outside of it), both to create more ILP in the inner loop and to be able to reuse the results of loads (`a_vec` doesn't depend on `x` so you can load it once and use the value multiple times). Compilers don't like to do that, so do it manually. BTW aren't these tiles far too small? IDK what specific sizes M1 wants but usually they're more like 128 to 512, nothing like 8 or 16.

Comment: ps. You're not particularly measuring Numpy performance, but the performance of whatever C library it's calling into. Read [Linear Algebra libraries](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html).

Comment: I'd transpose the matrix A prior to the actual computation.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE you can do that but proper tile-repacking is more effective

Comment: @harold could you give me a link to what proper tile-repacking is all about?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE the classic "Anatomy of High-Performance Matrix
Multiplication" spends a couple of pages on it (they just call it "packing", same thing though). Basically we find whatever memory order would be best, and then just put a chunk of the matrix in that order (it doesn't have to be the whole thing all at once, but it could be)

Comment: The best order doesn't end up being strictly transposed, it's mostly transposed but there are some peculiarities because after unrolling and tiling we wouldn't access A strictly column-by-column

Comment: @harold that's what I'm doing already, even in fft with the twiddle factors. thx anyway

Comment: This `float32x4_t a_vec = vdupq_n_f32(A[y * N + k]);` IMO is not too optimal -- one should load at least 4 -- possibly 8 adjacent values from `A` as well (loading a full block of 8x8 values is just 16 registers; then one can use `fmlaq_laneq_f32` instruction, which will essentially allow transposing the 8x8 subblock.

I would also use 4 separate accumulators.